# How to plot rownames and column names for a heatmap with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

This is a very basic question.  I could not find a satisfactory answer anywhere else so I am writing this up as a question here.  I have a matrix, a square matrix about 1300 x 1300.  I can use `matplotlib` to generate a heatmap from it.  However, I want the row and column names to show up on the heat map instead of the 0 -- 1300 that normally shows up when i use `imshow`.

I will put up an example shortly.

Comment: Take a look at the code I posted with a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43761430/multiple-1-dimensional-heatmaps-on-single-pcolormesh-matplotlib Although my question is asking something else, I think my code snippet has exactly what you're after and can be seen in the picture in that thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still have not put up your example, but I will give you a quick example of how to change the labels on each axis!

First, put your labels in an array, let's call them `y_labels` and `x_labels`

Now here is your code:

```
ax = pylab.subplots()
ax.set_yticklabels(y_labels)
ax.set_xticklabels(x_labels)
```

That should do the trick!